# how to solve this min-max optimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Can someone help me to solve this nonconvex problem.
I use Dual and KKT but it doesn't work.

[image]

I upload a picture .

my solution : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K04TA.png)

Comment: There is no $P$ in the constraints, or definition of $P$,  so it does not make sense at the moment. Once you fix this, simply add a new variable $t$ and add the constraints $P_i \leq t$ and then minimize $t$.

Comment: I use what you say for an other part of my problem, I want to solve it with other solution, I upload my way of solving this problem but I stuck in it.  thank you for your time , please see my uploaded answer @JohanLöfberg

Comment: You still don't have any $P$ in the model except in objective. Also, you appear to have a problem with integer variables, so talking about duals here makes me concerned.

Comment: i have p_i in my first condition and other conditions doesn't need any p_i @JohanLöfberg

Comment: Then fix your notation. You are using $P$ and $p$ which is very confusing.

Comment: sorry, all P is lower p , can you help me to solve it? @JohanLöfberg